# Loading TPL Files In A Popup

Tags: javascript, popup

Hi everyone how can i load a tpl file in a pop up for example.

This class displays a image and i want this as a button to trigger the pop up.

```
<div class="mlink_submitlink"> <a href=""></a> </div>
```

So when the above is clicked to load a tpl file in a pop up but would it be possible to not to load the file on page load only when clicked.

Can anyone help.

Comment: What is a `TPL` file?

Comment: You should edit that information into your post, @mike. You can click the `edit` link just underneath the tags for your post here in order to add more info. You might want to add a "smarty template" tag (if there is one).